# Convert plain text into object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

I have data in unordinary format `const variations`

```js
const variations = {
  0: "{"productPriceLocal": "16990.00", "productId": "30028132"}",
  1: "{"productPriceLocal": "22990.00", "productId": "30028233"}"
};

// this code doesn't work
// console.log(_.map(variations, 'productId'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script>
```

and I want this to convert to normal JS object like this, which with I can normally work

```js
const object = {
  0: {
    productId: 30028132,
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

I tried to use lodash, doesn't work well. Does Anyone know, what I should do?

Comment: "{"productPriceLocal": "16990.00", "productId": "30028132"}", this is not a valid string or object

Comment: Use JSON.parse() like explained here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem you have is that `"{"productPriceLocal": "16990.00", "productId": "30028132"}"` includes unescaped quotes that are terminating the string before you want it to (resulting in errors). So if you contain that string with single quotes your first problem should be fixed.

Then parsing the JSON objects as done below should produce the output you are looking for, no lodash nessecary.

```js
const variations = {
  0: '{"productPriceLocal": "16990.00", "productId": "30028132"}',
  1: '{"productPriceLocal": "22990.00", "productId": "30028233"}'
};

var output = {};

for(key in variations) {
  output[key] = JSON.parse(variations[key]);
}

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Array [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [Object.keys](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwia0cueoeTVAhXl64MKHaPkD24QFggoMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FObject%2Fkeys&usg=AFQjCNG8ofWu2NG52M-pj2pcIH1ewD2FJQ) methods to map your object to a single object of the type you're wanting.

```js
//Make sure you escape the quotes in your JSON strings.
const variations = {
      0: "{\"productPriceLocal\": \"16990.00\", \"productId\": \"30028132\"}",
      1: "{\"productPriceLocal\": \"22990.00\", \"productId\": \"30028233\"}"
    };

let parsedValues = Object.keys(variations) // Get keys as an array [0,1] 
  .reduce((obj, key) => { 
         // parse to an object.
         obj[key] = JSON.parse(variations[key]); 
         return obj; 
  }, {} /* initialization object */);
console.log(parsedValues);
```